# Update a db record in DJANGO with out having to use a form? EXAMPLE: Click to complete UPDATES a record

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-forms, django-views

I have an item in a list. I want to click something and have that click trigger a view. That view updates that list item's status in the db.

For example, add to cart, or save the date, or completed.

In each case, clicking that link will update the db record with a new status. Right now these are just boolean fields.

You can see where this is going. A URL tied to that view will be called with Ajax. But I'm trying to do this with graceful degradation. I know how to do the Ajax part, just not the db update part.

I've never done much more than the basic form.is_valid and form.save. So I'm a little lost.

Ideas welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
def some_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    my_obj = MyModel.object.filter(pk=kwargs['id'])
    if my_obj:
        my_obj = my_obj[0]
        my_obj.fancy_status = "someone wants to buy me!"
        my_obj.save()
    return some_appropriate_response()
```

with a url pattern like

```
(r'^/my_objects/(?P<id>\d{1,9})/buy/$', some_view)
```

seems to be what you're looking for, right?

Basically, you can save instances of your models just like you might think.

Comment: my_obj.fancy_status = "someone wants to buy me!" would populate the obj.fancy_status field with "someone wants to buy me!" - Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. Except, well, I was stupid, so in what I originally had that's a query set instead of a model instance. Fixing the code so it'll work as intended (ie, how you describe).